# how to update glue job version form AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

How to update glue job version form AWS CLI

I want to update **glue version 2** to **version 4**. I was trying to do with below command

`**aws glue update-job --job-name Glue_test1 --job-update --version 4.0**`

when I am trying its throwing below error.

***when calling the UpdateJob operation: Command should not be null.***